# How to perform click on DateRangePicker using Chrome Selenium C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, google-chrome

I am looking for a way to perform mouse click on DateRangePicker element.

I tried to write a tool for automation on https://rvshare.com/.
I need to click on DateRangePicker. I tried all the ways that are available on the internet but no luck.

Here are 3 ways I tried.

```
// 1.
Driver.FindElement(by).Click();

// 2.
Driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click('');", ((RemoteWebDriver)Driver).FindElement(by));

// 3.
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.MoveToElement(Driver.FindElement(by)).Perform();
action.Click(Driver.FindElement(by)).Perform();
```

The calendar controls are supposed to be shown but any of the above does not work.

Is there anybody who encountered similar issues?

Comment: What is the HTML for the DateRangePicker? Is the DateRangePicker an ASP.NET control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what was your problem, but I was able to click on Datepicker(Pickup or Dropoff) using 1st method you mentioned, so I suggest that issue is not with methods u r using, but with your locator.

Your code is gonna be:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='DateRangePickerInput_arrow DateRangePickerInput_arrow_1']/following::div[@class='DateInput DateInput_1']")).Click();
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I was so stupid trying to click the whole control. I was targetting the whole date range picker with xpath: "//*/div[@class='DateRangePicker DateRangePicker_1']". Thanks a lot. It saved me much time.

Comment: Precise and clean solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select the data from the calendar then use the below script once you click on the either `Pickup` or `Dropoff`. The xpath works for both of them. Make sure to enter the date in the right format and you month you want to select is there in the calendar. You have to click on `move to next month` button until you reach the required month.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//td[contains(@aria-label,'May 14, 2019')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it was not what I wanted to hear. Thanks anyway!